# Core Data Entity with several parent relationships

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

Let's say there is an entity called Product, which is connected to Shop (a shop has several products). However, there is also an entity called SpecialWebOffers, which also has a number of Products (which are not in any Shop).

How do I connect both Shop and SpecialOffers to Product. Is it OK to have two relationships in Product - one to Shop and one to SpecialWebOffers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very common for an entity to have multiple relationships.  If I am understanding your question correctly then the answer is yes.

Comment: Your wording "which are not in any Shop" makes me wonder if you meant that the relationships are mutually exclusive.  A Product can "belong" either to a Shop or a SpecialWebOffer.  Is this what you meant?

Comment: they could be in both, or could be exclusively in one or the other.